# Google drive API's not display folder

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to get folder list in shared drive folders of GD via REST in Postman. But I don't see these folders until I open it in the browser in UI

I can get the list of folders in Postman only after I opened root folder in browser

GEt request
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?supportsTeamDrives=true&includeTeamDriveItems=true&q=parents in 'folder_id'

Answer (score 0):

It's the other way around. `'folder_id' in parents`

Comment: This decision helped me